# How To Toggle User_Meta in frontend in a form using PHP

Tags: plugins, php, html, sql, front-end

I am trying to make a small form, that just has a submit button, and on submission, it should toggle user meta for the WordPress user. The button exists on frontend after content of post, and has a action too.

```
<form action="https://milyin.com?dark=true" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="test" id="test" onclick="https://milyin.com?dark=true"/><br/> </form>
```

The above was the html form code, i can assure that it echoes properly. Then i add the below line to trigger it. This is php

```
if (isset($_GET['dark'])){ 
testfun(); 
}
```

This calls a function called testfun, the function testfun is below:

```
function testfun(){
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$theme= get_user_meta($user_id, 'theme', true);
if ($theme == 'dark') {
   update_user_meta($user_id, 'theme', 'light');
   }
   else{
   update_user_meta($user_id, 'theme', 'dark');
   }
}
```

And obviously this code doesn't work, and i fail to figure our why. I have an intuition that the way i gey user id, can be wrong, because rest all seems to be fine. Anyhow please help me with this code.

I basically want to create a button that for the current logged in user, updated the user meta key 'theme' and toggles it between values 'light' and 'dark'

And as far as I am concerned i couldn't find anything wrong in it.

Comment: You should call the `testfun()` before you display the form - preferably in an early hook like `template_redirect`. Btw, your submit button contains an invalid `onclick` value.

Comment: Well l shall test the function and let you know... But whats wrong with my button, the form syntax seems correct... Please explain..

Comment: Hey I tested the function, i called it in some other function, and it works perfectly, the problem probably exists in the html or the if statement that calls the function..

Comment: The `onclick` attribute should contain a valid JS expression/code, but yours (which is an URL) is not a valid one. And that doesn't answer the question, but you should correct it anyway.

Comment: And can you re-clarify the question - is it when you submit the form, the function `testfun` doesn't run at all or that the meta value is not updated? Are you calling the function from within any hook or you just put it exactly below/after the form - `<form>...</form><?php // here you call the function? ?>`?

Comment: Well the function doesnt run... Anyways, i found the solution on my own... I shall put the answer soon... Thanks for the support, the problem was the if clause that calls the function...